# condition to check the existense of an entity using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, validation, stored-procedures, parameters

I have an stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetCOIOrganizations]  
(  
 @orgName varchar(75)   
)  
AS  
BEGIN  

 SET NOCOUNT ON  

 Select Id,  
  [Name],  
  Description,   
  AdmPersonId,  
  Active,  
  Reviewed,  
  DateCreated  
 FROM COIOrganization Org  
 WHERE Org.[Name] like @orgName + '%'  
  AND (Org.Reviewed = 0 OR (Org.Reviewed = 1 AND Org.Active = 1))  

 order by [Name] ASC  

END
```

I want to include a condition in this that if the entity(org.[Name]) already exists then give some validation. How do I do that?

Comment: i have tried this but then how do i check the flag?                    IF exists(select org.[Name] from COIOrganization Org)
        RAISERROR('entity already exists') AND set flag = 0
        else set flag = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IF [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188336(v=sql.105).aspx) check like this:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1
                1
            FROM
                COIOrganization Org
            WHERE
                Org.[Name] LIKE @orgName + '%' )
BEGIN
    SET
            flag = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET
            flag = 0
END
```